# Question about the hypens in a YAML file, when to use

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am wondering actually more confused when to use the hypen in a YAML file in this case for use in Azure DevOps. I included the below YAML file as a demonstration of what I mean.

I hopefully am correct that I found out that hypens **-** are used when we use list items. So if I look at jobs: there are more jobs so each job is preceded with a **-**

Steps have tasks so the individual tasks ate preceded with a **-**

But when I look at variables. I would have expected them to be some sort of list ( i am not a developer) so what are they? Because the individual variables are not preceded with a **-**

Same as Pool: it doesn't have a hypen.

Same with inputs: I would have expected a **-** here as well for the individual inputs. So maybe a better question is to ask what are the indivdual pool, variables and inputs seen as why no hypen is used. I just can't seem to find an answer.

I hope I explained it clearly enough.

Regards,

John

```
trigger:
- none
stages:

- stage: Build
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


jobs:
- job: Build


  variables:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'

  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      artifact: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- stage: Deploy
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job: Deploy

  steps:

  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      buildType: 'current'
      artifactName: 'drop'
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'


  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'tofreewebapp'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'freewebappdave'
      package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/*.*'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Comment: Hi John, If Flyx's answer is perfect to explain your question, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help others to find this answer when they have the same confusion, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

YAML has two kinds of collection nodes: *sequences* and *mappings*. When you use `-`, you indicate a sequence item. Sequence items are the content of sequences.

You use sequences when the identifying attribute of the contained values is their position. For example, for jobs, you have a first job, a second job and so on. Their order is meaningful and important.

Mappings on the other hand are collections that contain key-value-pairs. The key usually being a *scalar* (i.e. a textual value, like `pool` or `vmImage`) and the value being any kind of YAML node. For mappings, the identifying attribute of a value is its key. For example for variables, their order is not important, but their name is.

Mapping keys are usually indicated by a `:` after a scalar. So for example, `jobs:` is a mapping key `jobs` and indicates that its value follows. In our case, the value follows by means of a sequence.

Something that YAML does which can confuse people is that additional indentation for sequences is not necessary. For example, in this YAML

```yaml
a:
  b: c
d:
e:
```

it is obvious that the key `a` has the value `b: c`, which is a nested mapping. The key `d` has an empty value becauset the following key `e` is at the same level.

However, with sequences you can do

```yaml
a:
  - b
c:
- d
e:
```

Now, `a`'s value is obviously `- b`, i.e. a nested sequence. However, `c`'s values is, less obviously, also the nested sequence `- d`, while `e:` stops the previous sequence and starts a new value. This is important to understand the structure of your YAML file.

Now if you have a line like `- job: Build`, there are actually two things going on: `-` starts a sequence item, and `job:` starts a mapping which will be the value of this sequence item.

Mappings have two different uses: One use is that they identify substructures, such that for example a job has `variables` and `steps`. you cannot put a line `droggeljug:` in a job with some value, as that is not the name of a substructure. In `variables`, the mapping has a different use: You define any number of freely chosen names with corresponding values. It is a lookup table which you can later use to say „please give me the value mapped to `solution`“, and you will get `**/*.sln`.

So a YAML mapping is used for two different use-cases: Named substructures, and lookup tables (which is where the name *mapping* comes from). Even the root node of your YAML file is a mapping, with keys such as `trigger`, `stages`, `pool` etc.

Coming back to the question of why `variables` is not a list (or, in YAML terms, sequence): Variable names should be unique. In a sequence, you could have two items with identical name:

```yaml
variables:
  - solution: '**/*.sln'
  - solution: 'droggeljug'
```

In a YAML mapping, identical keys are forbidden. We don't use a sequence to clearly indicate that the keys must be unique.

The answer to the question of why `pool:` doesn't contain a sequence is a different one: This is a known substructure that just isn't a sequence. It is a structure that can contain a `name`, `demands` and `vmImage`, therefore it is given as YAML mapping. There cannot be multiple pools in here, so a sequence would make no sense.

Comment: Thank you so much Flyx it all makes perfect sense now. I appreciate the extra depth you provided and examples given.